# Return calculated value with rails query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a query:

```
@clients = Client.where(location_id: location).includes(:check_ins, :payments, :purchases).where("check_ins.created_at > ?", start_date).references(:check_ins)
```

that returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` array of `clients`.  Each client `has_many :payments` and each payment has an `:amount`.

For each client in the `ActiveRecord::Relation`, I'd like to include the sum of their payment amounts `client.payments.sum(:amount)`.  How can I get that returned in the array?

Comment: why do you want to include in each client object - instead you can calculate it from views right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Direct Solution

You can just always write a helper method:

```
class Client
  has_many: payments

  def total_payment_amount
    payments.sum(:amount)
  end
end
```

Then in your given code, you could just call it like the following or whereever you are gonna call it (like in the views for example):

```
@clients = Client.where(location_id: location).includes(:check_ins, :payments, :purchases).where("check_ins.created_at > ?", start_date).references(:check_ins)

@clients.each do |client|
  puts client.total_payment_amount
end
```

### SQL Query Solution

Or, if you actually instead want this value as part of the SQL so that you can even query on this further then:

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :payments
end
```

Then in your given code:

```
@clients = Client.select('SUM(payments.amount) AS total_payment_amount').joins(:payments)

@clients.each do |client|
  puts client.total_payment_amount
end
```